# VBscript print value from input box to file

Tags: vbscript

How can I print the `NUM` value that I get from the input box in to the file? (because I get in the file "NUM" and not the value of the `NUM`

```
NUM=InputBox("ENTER NUM")
.
.
.

CreateNewFile.Write ("add this line in file with NUM")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like you're putting `NUM` in quotation marks. That's going to instruct the computer to print the literal value "NUM" instead of printing the value of the variable `NUM`.

Try this instead:

```
CreateNewFile.Write NUM
```

**EDIT:** Ahh, if you need to print a line of text preceding the value of the variable, then you will need to *concatenate* the two items. The way to do that in VBScript is to use the `&` operator:

```
CreateNewFile.Write "add this line in file with " & NUM
```

Notice how I've added the string literal in quotation marks, but then closed them before specifying the name of the variable? This instructs the computer that it should treat them as two *separate* entities. Otherwise, it has no way of knowing that NUM isn't just part of your string.

Comment: but I need also to print "add this line in file with"